# Гражданин или гражданка?

Tags: употребление-слов

Пишу эссе на тему "Я - гражданин России"
Но все дело в том, что я девушка и пишу от женского лица, как мне себя называть"гражданин России" или "гражданка России"?

Comment: >Наша страна – это держава с многовековой историей, а значит, нас ждет светлое будущее!

Может я и излишне придираюсь, но из того, что у нас многовековая история, никаким образом нельзя сделать вывод, что нас ждёт великое прошлое. Фразу лучше перестроить.

Comment: В таком случае, вы может быть и правы. Но приведите для убедительности перефразированный пример. Буду благодарна!

Comment: Я не знаю ни цели сочинения, ни того, что вы хотите донести на читателя. Я лишь указал на то, что фраза алогична, из причины не выходит следствия. Если на рулетке 5 раз подряд выпадало красное, то это не значит, что так будет и на шестой.

Если оставлять патетичность, то фраза лучше перестроить так - *Наша страна – это держава с многовековой историей, и я верю, что нас ждет светлое будущее!*

Если работа нужна для участия в конкурсе, то лучше написать, что-нибудь задушевное, связанное с личным ощущением страны и своей роли в ней. Такие работы всегда будут смотреться выигрышнее голой патетики.

Comment: Вам удалось меня убедить! Спасибо за аргументированный ответ)

Answer (score 4):

Вы - гражданка. И только так.

Слова "гражданин" и "гражданка" вполне согласуются с полом. Т.е. использование "гражданин" по отношению к женщине никаким контекстом не предопределяется. Если Вы - гражданка, так и пишите.

Иное возможно (но не обязвтельно!) только в текстах особого патетического звучания, особой патриотической окраски... Не думаю, что эссе даже на такую высокую тему требует такого стиля. Так что пишете в женском роде, как Вам природа назначила.

Comment: Я - гражданин России.
Все люди, живущие на нашей огромной планете, имеют свой дом, свою страну, которую они считают своей Родиной. Моя Родина – Россия, и я горжусь тем, что я гражданин великой, многонациональной страны! Россия – сильная, независимая держава с вековыми традициями, которой восхищается мир. Каждый человек должен знать историю государства, в котором он живет, ведь без прошлого нет настоящего, а без настоящего – будущего. Наша страна  – это держава с многовековой историей, а значит, нас ждет светлое будущее!
Текст примерно такого характера. Написан для участия в конкурсе, связанно

Comment: со знанием таких наук как обществоведение.

Comment: В первой фразе я бы написала "гражданка", она нейтральна, а вот "я горжусь тем, что я гражданин великой" - "гражданин"

Comment: Спасибо Вам!

Comment: Я бы везде исправил на "гражданка".

Comment: И Вам спасибо!

Comment: Не стоит. 
Одного "спасиба" на всех вполне достаточно.

Answer (score 3):

Если текст публицистический, лучше употреблять "гражданин", гражданка- разговорный оттенок, в анкетах допускается, там нужен пол, а в высоких стилях нежелательно, хотя и возможно, теперь слово нейтральное.

Comment: Согласна с Людмилой. А вот и [источник информации](http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/147/Род_названий_лиц_женского_пола_по_профессии,_должности_и_т._д.) для пущей убедительности.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд лучше оставить "гражданин". С "гражданкой" как-то несерьёзно получается. Например, когда ко всему народу обращаются, говорят "Граждане России!", а не "Граждане и гражданки!"

Comment: Честно говоря, я думаю так же!

Comment: Ну, и не всегда так было.Вспомните(слышали-то почти все в разных кинохрониках)выступление Молотова 22 июня 1941 года: "Граждане и гражданки Советского Союза!"Скорее всего,как всегда референты-русскоязычники правили текст.

Comment: Не верьте кинофильмам. Там вставлялась "официальная" фонограмма.  
 
Больше всего меня убила фраза из "выступления" Молотова "Сегодня, 22 июня началась Великая Отечественная война". Ноу камментс.     
  
А что по сути - тогда уж "гражданинчики и гражданочки".

Comment: >Честно говоря, я думаю так же!  
  
Вы совершенно правы. Когда ко всем (или хотя бы к двум), то - граждане. Но сказать девушке "гражданин" я не рискну в самом страшном сне. И медаль "за заслуги перед Отечестом IV степени" гражданину Имярековой И.И. вручать поостерегусь.

Comment: -"Больше всего меня убила фраза из "выступления" Молотова "Сегодня, 22 июня началась Великая Отечественная война..." -

 А что ж это Вас убивает? как раз они("тонкошеие вожди")и решали как что называть идеологически. Кстати, Молотов там ошибку делает в ударении, он произнес "грАжданки".Это общеизвестный факт, войну ждали, заготовки лежали в папках,их достали и дело пошло.